# Source model not found for attribute "brand_pro"

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.7

I have created one custom module for product attribute.I am getting this error.Can anybody tell why is this error coming??
below i have given all the files that are required.I am not getting the errror please can some one help me out with this ..
config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <AdminModules_Brandattr>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </AdminModules_Brandattr>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <brandattr>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>AdminModules_Brandattr</module>
                <frontName>brandattr</frontName>
            </args>
        </brandattr>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <brandattr>
                <file>customerbrand.xml</file>
            </brandattr>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <brandattr>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>AdminModules_Brandattr</module>
                <frontName>brandattr</frontName>
            </args>
        </brandattr>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <models>
        <brandattr>
            <class>AdminModule_Brandattr_Model</class>
        </brandattr>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <brandattr_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>AdminModules_Brandattr</module>

            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </brandattr_setup>

        <brandattr_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </brandattr_write>

        <brandattr_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </brandattr_read>
    </resources>
</global>

<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <brandattr>
                    <class>brandattr/observer</class>
                    <method>productSave</method>
                </brandattr>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_prepare_save>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
  </config>
```

Unit.php

```
 <?php


 class AdminModules_Brandattr_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Unit extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract         
 {
  public function getAllOptions()
    {
      if ($this->_options === null) {
         $this->_options = array(
            array(
                'value' => '',
                'label' => '',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => '1',
                'label' => 'Only',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => '2',
                'label' => 'Vero Moda',
            ),

        );
    }
      return $this->_options;
   }
 }
```

?>

sqlsetup

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

 $setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_pro', array(
 'group'         => 'General',
 'input'         => 'select',
 'type'          => 'text',
 'label'         => 'Brand',
 'source'        => 'brandattr/product_attribute_source_unit',
 'backend'       => '',
 'visible'       => 1,
 'required'      => 0,
 'user_defined' => 1,
 'searchable' => 1,
 'filterable' => 0,
 'comparable'    => 1,
 'visible_on_front' => 1,
 'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
 'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
 'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: you have typo here:
        <brandattr>
            <class>AdminModule_Brandattr_Model</class>
        </brandattr>
should be:

        <brandattr>
            <class>AdminModules_Brandattr_Model</class>
        </brandattr>